# Show that $R/(I \cap J) \cong (R/I) \times (R/J) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, chinese-remainder-theorem

My question actually follows from this one:

[Chinese Remainder Theorem for Rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713935/show-that-if-i-j-r-then-r-i-cap-j-cong-r-i-times-r-j)

What I don't understand is why is it necessary for $I+J=R$, in order for

$$
\varphi\colon R\to R/I\times R/J:a\mapsto (a+I,a+J)
$$

to be surjective. This map seems surjective by construction (I worked through the same question myself and came up with the same homomorphism. But I didn't seem to require that $I+J=R$ in my answer).

> Quoting Ben West's answer, he says:
>
> For any $r,s\in R$, we can write $r=r_i+r_j$ and $s=s_i+s_j$, where
>   $r_i,s_i\in I$, etc. Let $a=r_i+s_j$, so $a-r=s_j-r_j\in J$, and
>   $a-s=r_i-s_i\in I$. In particular, $a+I=s+I$, and $a+J=r+J$. This
>   shows that the map $$ \varphi\colon R\to R/I\times R/J:a\mapsto
> (a+I,a+J) $$ is surjective.

Why does  $a-s \in I  $ $\Rightarrow a+I = s+I $ in the above argument?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a - s\in I$, then $a - s = x$ for some $x\in I$. Then $a = s + x$. Thus, for every $y \in I$, $a + y = s + (x + y) \in s + I$, showing that $a + I \subseteq s + I$. Similarly, $s + I \subseteq a + I$. Hence $a + I = s + I$.

If $I + J \neq R$, $\phi$ is not surjective. Just to illustrate, if $R = \Bbb Z$, $I = (3)$, and $J = (6)$, then $(2 + I, 3 + J)$ is not in the image of $\phi$. Otherwise, $\phi(a) = (2 + I, 3 + J)$ for some $a\in \Bbb Z$, which implies $a \equiv 2\pmod{3}$ and $a \equiv 3 \pmod{6}$. Since $a \equiv 3\pmod{6}$, $a = 3 + 6j$ for some $j\in \Bbb Z$. Since $3 + 6j \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$, then $a \equiv 0\pmod{3}$. This contradicts the congruence $a \equiv 2\pmod{3}$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I should have went one step further. I now see that $a+I = s+I$ and $a+J=r+J$, how does this then show that the map is surjective? Is it because then for any two arbitrary elements in $R$, there exists an element $a \in R$ which maps to that particular pair?

Comment: So given $r,s \in R$, $\phi(a) = (r + I, s + J)$, where $a = r_i + s_j$ in Ben's construction. This proves $\phi$ is surjective. Makes sense?

Comment: Ahh yes that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The map $\varphi\colon R\colon R/I\times R/J$ defined by $r\mapsto(r+I,r+J)$ is a ring homomorphism with kernel $I\cap J$, so it induces an *injective* homomorphism
$$
R/(I\cap J)\to R/I\times R/J
$$
which is also surjective if and only if $\varphi$ is surjective.

So, assume $\varphi$ is surjective. This means that $(1+I,0+J)=\varphi(r)$ for some $r$, that is
$$
r+I=1+I,\quad r+J=0+J
$$
Thus $1-r=x\in I$ and $r=y\in J$, which means $1=x+y\in I+J$, forcing $I+J=R$.

The converse, that is, $I+J=R$ implies $\varphi$ surjective, is easy.

Comment: Just wondering, is this an alternative answer to this question which you have answered? Or are they different? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1152991/converse-to-chinese-remainder-theorem/1244165#1244165

Comment: @Aha They are different, because here the canonical homomorphism is used. The other is more general.