# The difference between the ring version and module version of Chinese Remainder Thereom.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ideals, chinese-remainder-theorem

**Chinese Remainder Theorem for Commutative Rings** If $R$ is a commutative ring with $1$ and $I, J$ are ideals of $R$ that are pairwise coprime or comaximal (meaning $I + J = R$), then $IJ = I \cap J$, and the quotient ring $R/I \cap J$ is isomorphic to $R/I \times R/J$.

I will first prove that $IJ = I \cap J$.

If $x \in IJ$, then $x = \sum a_i b_i$ where $a_i \in I$ and $b_j \in J$. Thus for any fixed $i$, we have that $a_i b_i \in I$ since $a_i \in I$ and $a_i b_i \in J$ since $b_i \in J$. Thus, $\sum a_i b_i \in I$ and $\sum a_i b_i \in J$, which means that x = $\sum a_i b_i \in I \cap J$. Therefore, $IJ \in I \cap J$.

Note that since $R$ contains 1, we can write $I \cap J = R(I \cap J)$. Therefore, $I \cap J = R(I \cap J) = (I+J)(I \cap J) = I(I \cap J) + J(I \cap J) \subseteq IJ + JI = IJ$.

Now, I will prove that $R/IJ \cong R/I \times R/J$.

Consider the ring homomorphism $\phi: R \rightarrow R/I \times R/J$ defined by $\phi(r) = (r+ I, r+J)$ with kernel $I \cap J$. If we can prove that $\phi$ is surjective, then we can apply the first ring isomorphism theorem to show that $R/(I \cap J) \cong R/I \times R/J$.

Since $I + J = R$, for any $r_1, r_2 \in R$, we can write $r_1 = i_1 + j_1$ and $r_2 = i_2 + j_2$, where $i_1, i_2 \in I$ and $j_1, j_2 \in J$. Let $x = i_1 + j_2$. This gives us $x - r_1 = j_2 - j_1 \in J$ and $x - r_2 = i_1 - i_2 \in I$. In particular, we have $x + I = r_2 + I$ and $x + J = r_1 + J$. Hence, for all $(r_1 + I, r_2 + J)$, we can find an element $x$ such that $\phi(x) = ( x+ I, x+ J) = (r_2 +I, r_1 + J)$. This shows that $\phi$ is surjective.

Hence, we can conclude that $\phi: R/(I\cap J) \cong R/I \times R/J$.

**(Can someone verify if the proof is correct?)**

Using module homomorphism, the result also hold (I think.)

So, now my concern is proving the converse.

[Converse to Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1152991/converse-to-chinese-remainder-theorem)

According to this post the converse is false if the isomorphism is of rings. I don't quite understand how the link given shows this. I will put the link here: [Can $R \times R$ be isomorphic to $R$ as rings?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895428/can-r-times-r-be-isomorphic-to-r-as-rings) **Can someone explain to me how the result in this link shows that it is only true when the isomorphism is of $R$-modules?**

**If so, am I correct to say that chinese remainder theorem shows that $R/I \cap J \cong R/I \times R/J$ both as rings and $R$-modules, but the converse is only true when the isomorphism is of $R$-modules?**

What about this, [Show that $R/(I \cap J) \cong (R/I) \times (R/J) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1229867/show-that-r-i-cap-j-cong-r-i-times-r-j?lq=1)

**Can it be used to show that the converse is true by saying that since $\phi: R \rightarrow R/I \times R/J$ is surjective if and only if $I+J = R$, so $R/I \cap J \cong R/I \times R/J$ if and only if $I+J = R$** I think we cannot because in the post the $\phi$ is predefined, but here we are talking about the general case, $R/I \cap J \cong R/I \times R/J$ and the homomorphism might not be the same. Am I right?

I am very confused about this. Note that this is only my first algebra course, so please don't use stuff that is too advanced to explain to me. Thanks.

Comment: Your proof is correct and it works as a ring isomorphism and as a module isomorphism as well.

Comment: The converse holds for modules but not for rings. (For instance, note that $R\times R\not\simeq R$ as $R$-modules for any commutative unitary ring, so one can't produce similar conterexamples.)

Comment: @user26857 isn't the (solution of the) second link saying that it is possible to have $R \times R \cong R$ as rings?

Comment: @user26857 no, i meant this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895428/can-r-times-r-be-isomorphic-to-r-as-rings. Cos you say "The converse holds for modules but not for rings. (For instance, note that R×R≄R as R-modules for any commutative unitary ring, so one can't produce similar conterexamples.)" I don't quite understand this. Can you explain more?

Comment: In the link you just gave it $R\times R\simeq R$ as $R$-modules holds for some *non-commutative* ring (check it!). For a commutative unitary ring this is impossible! (Btw, I've corrected your question. Take a look at the last edit. If your concern was about a possible example of a ring $R$ such that $R\times R\simeq R$ as $R$-modules, then this comment made it clear that this is not possible for commutative unitary rings, but it's possible for non-commutative rings. I've also added a comment in this vein under the question you linked.)