# Proving that there exists $a\in R$ such that $a \equiv a_k \pmod{I_k}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $I_1,...,I_m$ be ideals of a ring $R$ such that $I_j+\cap_{k\neq j}I_k=R$ for every $j\in\{1,...,m\}$. Then if $a_1,...,a_m\in R$ there exists $a\in R$ such that $a \equiv a_k \pmod{I_k}$ for every $k\in\{1,...,m\}$.

Fix $k\in\{1,...,m\}$. To show $a \equiv a_k \pmod{I_k}$ (for some $a$) is equivalenltly to show that $a_k\in I_k+a$. Since $a_k\in R=I_k+\cap_{t\neq j}I_t$, then $a_k=b_k+c_k$ for some $b_k\in I_k$ and $c_k\in\cap_{t\neq j}I_t$. However, clearly this $c_k$ is not the same for all of the $a_k's$.

Would anyone give me a hint? Thank you.

Comment: However, I think in my problem I'm not assuming $R$ has $1$.@user26857

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1229867/show-that-r-i-cap-j-cong-r-i-times-r-j?lq=1) for the non-unitary case.